# Is there a way we can apply two vue.js libray on one element?

Tags: vue.js

For example, with vue draggable library we can drag an html element to another position. and with vue selectable libaray, it is possible to allow an element to be selected. But these two props are based on there each two different library.

Is there a way that we can mix in these two vue libraries in the same element, so we can make it draggable and selectable at the same time?

Thank you for your kindness.

Comment: maybe you can try this: https://github.com/stephan281094/vue-drag-select

Answer (score 0):

It's **not possible** to combine two components, especially since they are third party libraries and you don't have access to their source-code.

---

In general, however, there are a few possible solutions for your problem.

Instead of using component, you might want to [use directives](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html) instead. These can be stacked on a component as much as you like, and as such modify its behavior.

You might also be interested in creating [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html).